# How to pluralize "sexy"?

Tags: ortografía, adjetivos, plurales, extranjerismos

The anglicism [*sexy*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xm1zVv5) is accepted in Spanish, as you know (in the DLE it shows as *adj. [sexi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xl0uGvK). U. t. c. s. m.*)

When it's an adjective, how is its plural supposed to be built?

> *X persona* tiene ojos sexy(s).

I'm slightly inclined to think that it remains invariant.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Según el [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=sexi)

> Su plural es **sexis** (→ plural, 1e): «Sus patrocinadores las instaron a utilizar en el uniforme de competición pantaloncitos más pequeños y sexis» (GmzBartlett Eva [Esp. 2002]).
>
> ---
>
> Plural 1e) **Voces extranjeras terminadas en -y precedida de consonante.** Deben adaptarse gráficamente al español sustituyendo la -y por -i: dandi (del ingl. dandy); panti (del ingl. panty); ferri (del ingl. ferry). Su plural se forma, como el de las palabras españolas con esta terminación (→ a), añadiendo una -s: dandis, pantis, ferris. No son admisibles, por tanto, los plurales que conservan la -y del singular etimológico: dandys, pantys, ferrys.