# Concordancia de género en el plural con adjetivos disyunctivos

Tags: género

Si tenemos dos cosas que comparten un sustantivo y solo se diferencian por un adjetivo, es posible escribir el sustantivo en plural y los adjetivos en singular (ejemplos del DPD):

- Las razas negra y blanca
- Los sótanos primero y tercero (y quinto...etc)

No me resulta nada extraño esto.  Pero el otro día, estuve escribiendo un correo hablando de algunos programas que tenemos y a quién están dirigidos.  Todo bien, hasta que llegué a lo siguiente:

> orientado a los alumnos gais, [ *lesbianos* | *lesbianas* ] y transexuales.

Por definición, las lesbianas son mujeres y por lo tanto solo existen *alumnas lesbianas*, pero dada la concordancia normal, ya que se tiene *los alumnos* encabezando la unidad sustantival me suena mucho mejor en masculino.  EL DPD no habla de tal construcción en su artículo en concordancia.

Si por ejemplo hablásemos de algún tipo de pájaro cuyos machos fuesen de color rojo (solo) y cuyas hembras fuesen de color amarillo (solo), ¿cuál sería la forma mejor de referir a las amarillas en la siguiente frase (sin reduplicar ni el sustantivo ni artículo):

> Los pájaros rojos y [ *amarillos* | *amarillas* ]

O si hablamos de alumnos con condiciones médicas:

> Los alumnos parapléjicos, ciegos, [ *embarazados* | *embarazadas* ], etc.

¿Cómo os parece?  ¿Débese concordar en femenino o masculino?

Comment: podrías poner `orientado a los alumnos LGTB`

Comment: Por cierto, parece ser que "lesbiano" existe, pero se refiere a un oriundo de la isla de Lesbos, o la homosexualidad femenina. Por _alumnos lesbianos_ cabría entender un colectivo de esta isla, más que un colectivo exclusivamente femenino y homosexual.

Answer (score 5):

Yo creo que debe concordar con el sustantivo, como lo hace el artículo. Digamos que el mirlo es el ave que describes:

> Los mirlos rojos y amarillos.

Digamos que es un pez, y es la caballa

> Las caballas rojas y amarillas.

Aunque sepas que estás designado a un conjunto de la población con una determinada distinción de sexo, el adjetivo se refiere a **la clase**. Ten en cuenta además que se suele usar el masculino para hacer referencia conjuntos formados por seres de ambos sexos. `Alumnos` puede designar tanto a un colectivo mixto como formado exclusivamente por chicos.

Si quisieras referirte sólo a uno de los sexos de nuestras hipotéticas aves (rojos ellos; amarillas ellas) no dirías

> Los mirlos amarillas
>
> Las águilas rojos

Dicho esto, el problema es que no puede concordar en masculino en todos los casos porque algunos de esos adjetivos (o sustantivos) no admiten forma en masculino (ni *embarazados* ni *lesbianos*, aunque hay parejas que cuando esperan un bebé dicen "estamos embarazados" en lugar de "ella está embarazada". No sé hasta qué punto esto es correcto).

Así que creo que debería ser:

> Un programa para alumnos gais, lesbianas y transexuales
>
> Un programa orientado a alumnos ciegos, parapléjicos, embarazadas, etc

Entiendo que la pega está en que el texto es ambiguo, y puede parecer que ofreces el programa a, por ejemplo, alumnos ciegos (sólo alumnos, no cualquier ciego) y cualquier embarazada (no exclusivamente a alumnas embarazadas) y no quieres repetir *alumnas lesbianas y alumnos transexuales*), pero hay que tener en cuenta de nuevo que la forma masculina puede usarse para referirse a colectivos mixtos (a ciegos y ciegas, no sólo a ellos), por lo que todos esos adjetivos se refieren a colectivos mixtos, excepto "lesbianas" o "embarazadas" que por razones obvias no pueden serlo.

Cuando lo he visto escrito en algún cartel, lo resuelven con la dichosa arroba (alumn@s gais, lesbianas o trans), que personalmente no me gusta nada.

Entiendo que pasa igual con otros sustantivo o adjetivos que sólo puedan tener forma masculina, y si tienes esa conjunción de adjetivos tendrá que ir en masculino aunque el sustantivo y el artículo sean femeninos (si es que hay algún caso como este, porque no se me ocurre ninguno. [Quizá patán?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10223/5481)).

Comment: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5211/how-to-pluralize-sexy/5212#5212

Comment: @EmilioGort, en referencia a "Voces extranjeras terminadas en "y" precedida de **consonante**"??? Por qué es relevante?

Comment: por lo del gays, segun el DPD debería ser gais, como lo tiene guifa. no por nada, yo me entere cuando esa pregunta.

Comment: @EmilioGort, sí, es "gais" aunque por una regla distinta, pues la "y" va precedida de vocal: "la _y_ del singular mantiene en plural su carácter vocálico y, por lo tanto, debe pasar a escribirse _i_. Corrijo mi respuesta. Gracias por señalarlo.

Comment: +1 sólo por lo de odiar la arroba. Te pondría otro por el resto de la respuesta. Como nota: no se utiliza el masculino para referirse a conjuntos formados por ambos sexos. Para eso se utiliza el neutro, que tiene la misma forma que el masculino (herencia del latín).

Comment: @Envite, gracias por el apunte de lo de neutro vs. masculino.

Answer (score 5):

Te puedes saltar la concordancia con una pequeña perífrasis:

> orientado a los alumnos **que sean** gais, lesbianas y transexuales.
>
> Los alumnos **que estén** parapléjicos, ciegos, embarazadas, etc.

En estos casos "los alumnos" queda en género neutro, con la forma del masculino, y los adjetivos se ponen también en neutro salvo que no lo admitan.

Answer (score 4):

No sé si estoy en lo correcto, pero si un sustantivo se refiere a una categoría o grupo de elementos, entre los cuales encontramos elementos de género masculino y femenino, al referirme a alguno de esos elementos utilizaré el género de ese elemento:

> Los alumnos parapléjicos, ciegos, embarazadas, etc.

Desde luego que me suena mal, pero de la otra forma también. Para evitar estas situaciones recurro a las mismas técnicas que las empleadas para el lenguaje política y gramáticamente correcto en temas de género:

> Los alumnos (quizás "el alumnado") [afectados de | que sufran] paraplejia, ceguera, embarazo, etc.

Pero todo esto es muy discutible. Los ejemplos que incluye Diego en su respuesta yo los dejaría tal cual, porque entiendo que un pájaro puede ser hembra o macho, al igual que un pez o una caballa. Yo no digo "un caballo macho", pero tampoco digo "un alumno embarazado".
De alguna forma encuentro casos en los que prefiero la concordancia con el género del elemento y otros en los que la prefiero con el de la categoría.

Answer (score 0):

has caído en una contradicción, y no hay buena solución, por lo tanto hay que ajustar la frase, por ejemplo

> orientado a los gais, lesbianas y transexuales.

Esto funciona bien porque el masculino abarca lo masculino y lo femenino en una lista mixta.

Funciona también en tu último ejemplo (que me pareció el mejor ejemplo de la contradicción que encontraste):

> orientado a los parapléjicos, ciegos, embarazadas, etc.

De hecho, me gusta más la frase así, sin "los alumnos," que está de más.