# Declension of the word "patán"

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, declinación

How does one decline (if at all) the adjective *patán*?

We all know there's inconsistencies in languages and I was thinking about this adjective. My intuition tells me it should be declined, but it sounds off.

Is the proper way to decline it

> Ella es una patana.
>   ¡Qué patana es ella!

or rather:

> Ella es una patán.
>   ¡Qué patán es ella!

What are some common adjectives that wouldn't get declined [either]? I can think of some, but they're mostly recent foreign additions to the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acute nouns ending in -n and -s are adding a feminine -a, except for "barón" (fem: "baronesa") and "edecán" and "rehén" (used for both genders).

To form the feminine of adjectives ending in -or, -ol, -ón, -án, -ín and -és, is added -a to each, except for "cortés".

The correct feminine:

> ¡Eres una patana!

Comment: This seems to support the RAE tweet. Could I get a source on this rule?

Comment: Diccionario panhispánico de dudas: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg

Answer (score 2):

Actually I can't comment but as a spanish I can tell, you can say "machota", sounds weird even for me.Is more like a suburban word, but actually RAE have it.
http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=machota
It's saying a woman its kind of tomboy/ not very "femenine" or you can even say it like "you are very strong".

```
¡Qué machota eres!
```

But I never recommend you to say patana, even if RAE say so:
https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/327219334017581057

Comment: Interesting! That tweet contradicts the current top post. It's not in the dictionary but it seems the RAE actually recognizes it as the proper declension.

Comment: yes, I can't find it either,it's not a used word for people, even patán.Maybe the "closest" word to patán is paleto, and there you have the femenine easily "paleta". you are making me curious even with my own language I never questioned myself with these things.

Answer (score 1):

`Patán` is a masculine form, [according to the RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=pat%E1n). It is a noun that can be used as an adjective.

The article must agree with number and gender (so *una patán* is incorrect).

The correct form, [according to this source](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/327219334017581057) would be:

> Ella es una patana.

What I can't tell you is up to which point you can use that adjective (or noun) to refer to a woman. Sounds to me that is like saying

> Ella es un *machote*

([*Machote*](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=machote) stands, among other things, as a brave bold **man**). You won't use *machota*, and despite gender concordances people will understand that you are trying to allocate the connotations or attributes of that noun or adjective to that person.

Answer (score 1):

> patán.
>
> (De pata).
>
> 1. m. coloq. Aldea**no** rústi**co**.
> 2. m. coloq. **Hombre** zafio y tosco. U. t. c. adj.

This word can't be used on women, it is only for men. Using it with women it could sound as a joke, so saying:

> - ¡Eres una patana!
> - ¡Eres una patán!

Is the same thing for me, since feminine form doesn't exist you can play with the word, but *patana* has a stronger joking meaning. I've never hear it before in this way but I see no problem but this can't be used in formal environments, texts, etc. You can say it with friends or just as a joke, in chatting or even on literature to sound funny and closer to people, sometimes writers use *incorrect* words this way.