# ¿Cómo se forman los plurales de los extranjerismos crudos?

Tags: ortografía, plurales, extranjerismos

Buscando sinónimos de *reunión* para el Translation-golf, me encuentro (no sin cierta sorpresa) que el diccionario acepta:

> ***[party](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S1WTeWK)***
>
> Voz ingl.
>
> 1. m. **fiesta** (‖ reunión para divertirse).

Así pues, la voz *fiesta* se incluye como un extranjerismo crudo. Cuando quise usarla en el texto (cosa que acabé descartando) me di cuenta de que tenía que usarla en plural. Y entonces me di cuenta de que no estaba seguro de cómo formarlo.

Imagino que al ser un extranjerismo crudo no sigue las normas para palabras españolas o extranjerismos adaptados, por lo que no sería ni *partyes* (añadiendo *-es* como en *reyes*) ni *partis* (cambiando *-y* por *-is* como en *jerséis*).

¿Cómo se forman entonces los plurales de los extranjerismos crudos? ¿Se dejan invariables? ¿Se siguen las normas del idioma de origen de la palabra? ¿Y si no se sabe cómo se forman los plurales en el idioma de origen?

Comment: Relacionada: [_How to pluralize “sexy”?_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5211/12637) La respuesta aceptada incluye cómo formar el plural del ejemplo (_partis_), pero me interesa saber si hay una norma general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La [Nueva gramática de la lengua](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QnEagpjRqqUfSrlm) dice sobre los plurales de extranjerismos crudos:

> **3.4c** Los llamados **EXTRANJERISMOS CRUDOS**, que conservan la pronunciación y la grafía originarias, **forman el plural de acuerdo con las reglas de la lengua a la que corresponden**, lo que no compete a la morfología del español. Así, el plural de la voz alemana *lied* ('canción') es *lieder*, y los de las inglesas *man* ('hombre') y *woman* ('mujer') son *men* y *women*, respectivamente. Cuando se utilizan estas voces en un texto en español, se recomienda que sean marcadas con algún resalte tipográfico, por lo común la letra cursiva. Esta es la forma en la que el *DRAE* registra en la actualidad los sustantivos de este grupo, cuando son recogidos en él. distinto es el caso de los sustantivos y adjetivos extranjeros que aparecen en los diccionarios como palabras castellanizadas. La tendencia general es que estas otras palabras se atengan a las reglas de formación de plural que rigen para las demás voces españolas. Aun así, se documentan numerosos casos particulares, como se explicará en los apartados que siguen. Como en otras secciones de los capítulos de morfología de esta obra, solo en algunos casos se dará información relativa a la extensión geográfica de las voces que se mencionan, en favor de la síntesis expositiva.

Comment: Menuda forma de tirar la piedra y esconder la mano, ¿no? Te ponen una voz extranjera en el diccionario (sí, [_lied_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NHY965E) también la recoge el DLE) pero luego apáñatelas para saber cuál es el plural...

Comment: Eso parece, si quieres ponerlo en plural deberías saber como es el plural en el idioma correspondiente

Comment: Más bien me parece que te dicen que, puesto que esas palabras son extranjeras, no es asunto de la RAE (o de la ASALE) cómo se forman sus plurales. Al usar extranjerismos crudos te estás apartando de las normas del castellano, al fin y al cabo.